# How to transform a DataFrame[result : String] in scala into multiple rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and scala things. I am using an NLP package to analysis a book. The NLP method gives result `spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: string]` looks like:

```
|     Result|
| a, b, c, d|
|      e,f,g|
```

**In order to calculate numbers every word appears**, I want to separate a string into multiple rows like:

```
|Result|
|     a|
|     b|
|     c|
|   ...|
```

**Or do you have any suggestions about how to do words count based on a DataFrame with structure [result: string]?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spark sql function `explode` will help in this use case.

Refer the below sample code; I also added the word count step:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val rows = List(
  "a, b, c, d",
  "a,b,c,d",
  "e,f,g"
)
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows).toDF("Result")
df.show()
//  +----------+
//  |    Result|
//  +----------+
//  |a, b, c, d|
//  |   a,b,c,d|
//  |     e,f,g|
//  +----------+

val allWords = df.select(explode(split(col("Result"), ",")).as("Result"))
allWords.show()
//  +------+
//  |Result|
//  +------+
//  |     a|
//  |     b|
//  |     c|
//  |     d|
//  |     a|
//  |     b|
//  |     c|
//  |     d|
//  |     e|
//  |     f|
//  |     g|
//  +------+

val countPerWord = allWords.groupBy(trim(col("Result")).alias("Result"))
  .agg(countDistinct("Result").alias("Count"))
countPerWord.show()
//  +------+-----+
//  |Result|Count|
//  +------+-----+
//  |     g|    1|
//  |     f|    1|
//  |     e|    1|
//  |     d|    2|
//  |     c|    2|
//  |     b|    2|
//  |     a|    2|
//  +------+-----+
```